# Import JSON in SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, import

I want to import the following JSON file into SQL Server

```
{
  "Positions" : [
    {
      "Position" : {
        "code" : 5000042479,
        "Company" : "IN0009",
        "Region" : "APAC"
      }
    },
    {
      "Position" : {
        "code" : 1432042479,
        "Company" : "IN0010",
        "Region" : "SAFG"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

What I've tried so far is this:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(1000) 
SELECT
   @json = N'{
 "Positions" : [ { "Position" : { "code" : 5000042479,
   "Company" : "IN0009",
   "Region" : "APAC" } },
   { "Position" : { "code" : 1432042479,
   "Company" : "IN0010",
   "Region" : "SAFG" } } ] }'
 
   SELECT
      [Position.code],
      [Position.Company],
      [Position.Region] 
   FROM
      OPENJSON (@json, '$.Positions') WITH ( [Position.code] varchar(20), [Position.Company] varchar(20), [Position.Region] INT ) AS Pos
```

But the problem is that it returns NULL values:

```
+---------------+------------------+-----------------+
| Position.code | Position.Company | Position.Region |
+---------------+------------------+-----------------+
| NULL          | NULL             | NULL            |
+---------------+------------------+-----------------+
| NULL          | NULL             | NULL            |
+---------------+------------------+-----------------+
```

How should I read the values? Is there a way to dynamically get the column names from JSON without declaring them as I did. `[Position.code] varchar(20), [Position.Company] varchar(20)...` etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the correct `path` expression for each column in the explicit schema (and the correct data type for the `Position.Region` column):

JSON:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(1000) 
SELECT @json = N'{
  "Positions" : [
    {
      "Position" : {
        "code" : 5000042479,
        "Company" : "IN0009",
        "Region" : "APAC"
      }
    },
    {
      "Position" : {
        "code" : 1432042479,
        "Company" : "IN0010",
        "Region" : "SAFG"
      }
    }
  ]
}'
```

Statement:

```
SELECT
   [Position.code],
   [Position.Company],
   [Position.Region] 
FROM
   OPENJSON (@json, '$.Positions') WITH ( 
      [Position.code] varchar(20) '$.Position.code', 
      [Position.Company] varchar(20) '$.Position.Company', 
      [Position.Region] varchar(20) '$.Position.Region' 
   ) AS Pos
```

Result:

```
Position.code   Position.Company    Position.Region
5000042479      IN0009              APAC
1432042479      IN0010              SAFG
```

If the `$.Positions` JSON array has a fixed structure and you want to get the name of each key (if you want to build a dynamic statement), simply parse the first item in this JSON array with `OPENJSON()` and default schema:

```
SELECT [key]
FROM OPENJSON (@json, '$.Positions[0].Position')
```

Result:

```
key
-------
code
Company
Region
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple layers of JSON here, so you can nest the `OPENJSON` functionality:

```sql
SELECT PP.code,
       PP.Company,
       PP.Region 
FROM
    OPENJSON(@json, '$.Positions')
        WITH (Position nvarchar(MAX) AS JSON) P
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(P.Position,'$')
                    WITH(code varchar(20),
                         Company varchar(20),
                         Region int) PP;
```

Note this returns the error below error, as I have copied your defined data types in your question:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'APAC' to data type int.

I assume `Region` should really be a `varchar(4)`. If it is, this works fine.